# Parsing JSON into python without API

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get JSON into my python script, but it does not seem to work.

I have tried everything i can come up with. I really dont' know what else to try, any tip is appriciated

```
   jsonfile = 'D://python//tracker4R101-master//firefly- 
   master//countr_phonecode.json'
   dial_json = json.loads(jsonfile)
   dial_code = dial_json['dial_code']
   country_code = obj['country_code']
```

I expect the output to be something like

- Dial Code: (dial code)

The error message is:

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

If you need further code or explaning just let me know, i rarely post on stackoverflow, so i don't know what information to provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two functions `json.load` and 'json.loads`.`
load`lets you pass a file like object, while`loads` lets you pass a json encoded string.

So if you would like to read from a file your code should be something like:

```py
    jsonfile_path = 'D://python//tracker4R101-master//firefly-master//countr_phonecode.json'

    # open the file
    with open(jsonfile_path, 'r') as jsonfile:
        dial_json = json.load(jsonfile)

    dial_code = dial_json['dial_code']
    country_code = obj['country_code']
```

You could also read the file object and pass the string like json object to the library:

```py
    jsonfile_path = 'D://python//tracker4R101-master//firefly-master//countr_phonecode.json'

    # open the file and read its contents
    with open(jsonfile_path, 'r') as jsonfile:
        jsonfile_contents = jsonfile.read()

    dial_json = json.loads(jsonfile_contents)
    dial_code = dial_json['dial_code']
    country_code = obj['country_code']
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of the error. But now i get a new one. TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. The error comes from line 50: dial_code = dial_json['dial_code']